# Unpacked Chrome extension not showing up in Extensions folder in Chrome Profile

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, chrome-profile

I unpacked and loaded an extension for Chrome, https://github.com/iamadamdev/bypass-paywalls-chrome, but I need to find its corresponding folder in the Extensions folder in the Chrome profile path  /Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/ and I can't find it there.

The rest of my Chrome extensions are there though, but those were installed directly from the Chrome Web Store whereas this one was unpacked with developer mode, so I'm wondering if that's the issue? If it is, or if it's due to something else, is there a way to fix this? I need to find it for my Selenium-based project, where the WebDriver opens up the Chrome browser with an extension preloaded, following https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/

Comment: Unpacked extensions don't get copied there. They run right from their directory.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to still satisfy step 11 from the second link I posted? I've tried using the path to the unzipped extension contents, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a specific file I need to target, like an .crx file or something? Thanks

Comment: That blog is weird. Can you use the standard `add_extension` instead? Examples should be easy to find.

Comment: Nevermind, I just made sure my default Chrome profile had the external extension loaded and used options.add_argument("user-data-dir=<path to default Chrome profile>") and it worked!